# Mixed languages and sub-projects with .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, build, f#

I have a project primarily written in F# that uses a component written in C#. It is building fine on Windows with Visual Studio and on Linux and OS X using Makefiles.

I'm trying to port it to [.NET Core](http://dotnet.github.io/), which has its own build system, `dotnet build`. I'm having difficulty replicating the nested project handling of my existing build systems under it. That is, I want it to build the C# DLL, then build and link the F# executable project to it.

I tried to do without DLLs, but each `project.json` file can apparently only reference files in one language. If you try to add a C# file to the `compileFiles` list of an F# project file, `dotnet build` complains that it can't compile `Foo.cs` with `fsc`.

My C# project is in a subdirectory of the F# project, named after the namespace it implements, so I created a new .NET Core C# DLL project in that directory, but now I don't see how to tie the two projects together.

The `dependencies` feature of the [project file format](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Project.json-file) doesn't seem to solve this sort of problem. If the DLL project is in `Foo/Bar` and it implements the `Foo.Bar` namespace, `dotnet restore` fails to find it with this dependency reference:

```
"dependencies": {
    ...other stuff...
    "Foo.Bar": "*"
},
```

Apparently it can only search NuGet for dependencies. I don't want to ship the component to NuGet purely so that `dotnet restore` can find it.

I don't want to use [`bin` syntax](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Project.json-file#user-content-bin-syntax-wrapping-a-dll) to reference the built DLL because that would require a 2-pass build and a third `project.json` file. (One for the F# project, one for the C# project, and one to reference the built DLL.) Even then, I still don't see how to tie the first project to the third.

Surely there's a simple way to have a nested build tree with `dotnet build`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that one project is nested under the other. If you put them side by side (say, `/src/RootProj` and `/src/Foo.Bar`), you should be able to reference the `Foo.Bar` project with:

```
"dependencies": { 
  "Foo.Bar": "*" 
}
```

---

The dnx project system is cop..., ahem, *heavily influenced* by that of NodeJS, thus the reliance on directory structure to infer certain attributes.

The projects are expected to be located in subfolders of the root, and each is expected to have its own `project.json` file. The "root" itself comes from the `global.json` file located up the folder tree. The tooling traverses the folders up from the "current" one until it finds a `global.json`. The folder with `global.json` is then considered the "root of all roots". If you just create your solution from a template, you will have something like this:

```
/solution
   global.json
   /src
      /project1
         project.json
         File.cs
      /project2
         project.json
         File.cs
   /tests
      /testproject1
         project.json
         File.cs
```

When you are in any of the subfolders, the tooling will know the solution root by traversing the folders up. Similar to how `git` works.

If you look at the `global.json` file, you will probably see something like this:

```
{
    "projects": ["src", "tests"]
}
```

This means that the dnx tooling will expect to find projects under `/src` and `/tests`, that's it.

Now, from this, I can infer one other possible solution. Haven't tried it myself, but it just *might* work. Instead of moving your `Foo.Bar` project out to `/src`, you can add the path to it to `projects` in `global.json`:

```
{
    "projects": ["src", "tests", "src/Project1/Foo.Bar"]
}
```

Like I said, not sure if this will work or create some other subtle inconsistencies. Try it out.